# Magento 2.3 display logged in/out message using private content

Tags: magento2.3, knockout, customer-data

Does anyone have an example on how to display a logged in vs logged out message on frontend to customer that's not affected by cache without using the cache=false tag and hole punching the whole page

I'm assuming using knockout / section / customerData / private content somehow.

I've read a lot of tutorials and responses like this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/261067/70343

But just looking for an example on how to do this

Comment: Although the ans provided by me on the link that you shared is definitely sufficient to perform the needed. But if you are still unable to do so I may suggest having a look at default coding, look how magento shows Customer name in top header only for logged in customer, hope that may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just dive in Magento core coding it-self in order to have a better understanding.

Magento shows customer name for logged in customers only and not for guest customers, you may have a look at code responsible for that here:

```
vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/header.phtml
```

A already created customer section is used in this file have a look here:

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                "components": {
                    "customer": {
                        "component": "Magento_Customer/js/view/customer"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Then binded by knockout as :

```
data-bind="scope: 'customer'"
```

Accessed as :

```
customer().fullname
```

Here a pre existing section is been utilized if needed you may create your custom section as well, depending on your need.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Narendra certainly pointed me in the right direction.

Here is a complete example.

https://github.com/DominicWatts/CustomerLogin/blob/master/view/frontend/templates/index/index.phtml

```
<div class="greet welcome" data-bind="scope: 'customer'">
    <!-- ko if: customer().fullname  -->
    <span class="logged-in"
          data-bind="text: new String('<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Welcome back %1', '%1')) ?>').replace('%1', customer().firstname)">
    </span>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko ifnot: customer().fullname  -->
    <span class="not-logged-in"
          data-bind='html:"<?= $block->escapeHtml(__("Please <a href='%1'>login</a>", $block->getUrl('customer/account/login'))) ?>"'>
    </span>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "*": {
        "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
            "components": {
                "customer": {
                    "component": "Magento_Customer/js/view/customer"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```